# Git file commit history rewrite - git rev-list as git log

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, git-svn

I have just converted an svn repositry in to git with all history ,all things goes fine.
when I try to get changes in a specific file using

```
git log --follow -p -- WEB-INF/pages/search.html
git rev-list --all --full-history --pretty=oneline WEB-INF/pages/search.html
```

it show changes in 19 commits.

when I try to look commits without --full-history
    git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline WEB-INF/pages/search.html
or file history in bitbucket or in IntelliJ Idea it show 2 commits.

trying to rewrite history using git-filter-branch and git rev-list to be shown all 19 commit

Answer (score 0):

What shows up in `git log` if you remove the `--follow` option ?

---

`--follow` tells `git log` to try to detect file renaming while scanning the history.

AFAIK, `git rev-list` does not have a similar option, so if your file "search.html" was renamed (or moved from another directory) 2 commits ago, only those two commits will show up in `git rev-list`.

Comment: Thanks. after removing --follow it shows 2 commits.

Comment: can I rewrite history to get all 19 commits, renames and moves too , any helping command?

Comment: For rewriting history on a smaller scale (e.g : edit a specifc file by hand), look at `git rebase -i`

Comment: I want to rewrite history for all files in repository. trying add rename/moved filed history too in commits history.
trying to make result as git logs same as git log --follow. need to save same history for both. Repositry already have 5000 commits